# Developer Package missing in .NET SDK5 docker image

Tags: c#, .net, linux, docker, sdk

I am trying to publish a c# project via docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` (https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/).

In one of the `*.csproj` files is a definition like `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

I am getting the following error

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.301/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1216,5): error MSB3644: 
The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found. 
To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. 
You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

I have tried to install some dependencies from https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime-deps/ but this doesnt help me out.

I have searched hours to find a tutorial to install *Developer Packs* in linux distributions but found nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: you'll have to convert the project to .net (core) 5. .net framework stuff doesn't automatically work on linux.

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks for the feedback. I have converted the orject to .net (core) 5 and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing **Net Core** with **Net Framework**.

To use **Net Core**:
In .csproj file Change `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>` to `<TargetFrameworkVersion>net5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` and fix the dependencies to work with **Net Core**

To use **Net Framework**: Change the docker image to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.6`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.6` seems only available for windows container (see https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk).

Comment: `Net Framework` is only for Windows, `Net Core` is multi platform, that's why I give you the two options to resolve your issue.